# Webpack watch() with multiple entry points - emitting bundles for non-changed files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, browser-sync

In my `webpack.config.js` I have 3 separate entry points, one for the *JS bundle*, one for the *main SCSS bundle*, and one for a *separate SCSS bundle* that has no relationship with the main SCSS bundle.

When I use the `webpack.watch()` API, for some reason editing, say, the JS source files, causes not only the JS bundle to be recompiled, but also the 2 SCSS bundles.
**Why is this, and how can I stop this behaviour and ensure that only the entry point that is edited is recompiled?**

The reason this is an issue is I'm using `browsersync`, and for CSS bundle recompiles I'm just injecting the CSS instead of reloading, but on HTML/JS edits its reloading. However if I edit the SCSS and it also recompiles the JS/HTML `browsersync` triggers a reload instead of a CSS inject.

Comment: Make sure [cache](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/other-options/#cache) is not disabled.

Comment: Can you copy/paste your webpack config here?

Comment: Is it still actual? I'm using `Webpack` + `Browsersync` and for me a situation like this is working well. I could help you if still interested on this...

Answer (score 1):

In that case you need a file that let webpack detect how many changes have be done on each different entry point.

For that, you can use the ***manifest*** file provided by ***commonsChunkPlugin***:

For example, if you have the following entry points:

```
entry: {
   app: 'main.js', // main entry point
   vendor: ['jquery', 'react'] //Third libraries
}
```

You can use the plugin CommonsChunkPlugin:

```
new wepack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
  name: ['vendor', 'manifest']
})
```

This configuration generates a manifest file as another output. In that case, if you make a change in your *'app*' entry point, webpack are only going to recompile the main.js output bundle (according the *'filename'* format in the *'output'* configuration) because the vendor bundle is already the same.

You can try that with your specific entry points.